# Why is git wanting to track a file that is in an ignore folder

Tags: git

I have configured my .gitignore file to exclude a folder and all sub items within that folder

```
/src/web/sc/**/*.*
```

Now when I run git status it is reporting to me that I need to add an untracked files via command line it says I need to add
src/web/sc/shell

If I use TortoiseGit it lists more information it includes a file that is very nested within the tree.

src/web/sc/shell/client/Business Component Library/version 2/assets/lib/deps/d3/LICENSE

There are plenty of other folders and files withing the sc folder that are not being tracked, or being reported by git that I need to add untracked files. There are even files within the d3 folder that are not being flagged by git that need to be tracked.

I have looked for a solution, but all the questions relate to adding an untracked file into an excluded folder. I have the opposite. I want to know why a file that should never be tracked, git wants to track

I did try running git check-ignore directly on the file specified via TortoiseGit, and on the folder that is specified by the command line, but nothing is returned.

As a last resort I could include the full path / file in my ignore file, but I would like to understand why this file is being included.

**Update 1**

running

```
git rm --cached src/web/sc/shell
```

or

```
git rm --cached src/web/sc/shell/client/Business\ Component\ Library/version\ 2/Assets/lib/deps/D3/LICENSE
```

or after navigating to the specific folder

```
git rm --cached LICENSE
```

returns fatal: pathspec did not match any files

**Update 2**

This is what is returned when I run git status

> Untracked files:   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be
>   committed)
>
> ```
>     src/web/sc/shell/
> ```

Answer (score 4):

It's generally a good idea to paste exact text (e.g., `git status` output).  However, I noticed the following:

> `/src/web/sc/**/*.*`
>   [snip]
>   src/web/sc/shell/client/Business Component Library/version 2/assets/lib/deps/d3/LICENSE

Consider that last file name, `LICENSE`, and the expansion of the `ignore` directive, which ends with `*.*`.

Exercise: Is there a dot (`.`) in the name `LICENSE`?

Consider the simpler ignore pattern `/src/web/sc/*`.  (This may be an incorrect/inappropriate pattern if you *do* want to track files within the `sc` directory, but not any files in any subdirectory.)